# Changing the margin of a single list item in a div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a list of items wrapped inside a div tag

```
<div id="contentleft">
<ul>
<li><a href="http://www.google.com">Google<a/></li> //1
<li><a href="http://www.cnn.com">CNN<a/></li> //2
<li><a href="http://www.ign.com">IGN<a/></li> //3
<li><a href="http://www.bing.com">Bing<a/></li> //4
</ul>
```

I need to target the `<li>` in #2: and change its margin left to 30px using the `:eq()` `filter`, and `css()`. How would I do this? I would like an explanation, so I'll know what I'm doing more than just having an answer.

This is what I have tried:

```
$("#contentleft ul").eq(0).filter("li").css("margin-left:30");
```

Answer (score 6):

You are very close, with a couple of issues:

1) I don't know if it's a copy-paste issue, but your anchor tags are incorrect:

```
<a href="http://www.google.com">Google<a/>
```

Should be

```
<a href="http://www.google.com">Google</a>  // <-- slash before the "a"
```

2) `.eq()` needs to go on the element you are indexing, in this case the `li`.  `eq()` is also 0-based, so the second element would be `eq(1)`.  `.eq()` is interchangeable with `:eq()` inside the selector:

`$("#contentleft ul li:eq(1)")` or `$("#contentleft ul li").eq(1)`

3) `.css()` takes either 2 arguments, style/value, or an object:

```
$("#contentleft ul li:eq(1)").css("margin-left", "30px");
```

or

```
$("#contentleft ul li:eq(1)").css({
    "margin-left": "30px",
    "background-color": "purple"
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/gLKMj/

Answer (score 2):

First off you can find the answer almost EXACTLY on the jquery .eq() page here: http://api.jquery.com/eq/

But in case you don't have internet access:

```
// select the 2nd li element (zero based array so 1 is 2nd)
// change the margin-left to 30px
$('li').eq(1).css('margin-left', '30px');
```

Comment: *"But in case you don't have internet access:"* If not, then I'd love to know how OP posted the question, or could be reading your answer.